# Array = complexe data type = class?

Tags: java, arrays, class, data-structures

I learned that there are two types of data types (**complex** and **primitive**). The difference should lie in the fact that the complex data types have or can output more than one content. I have noted String or the scanner as examples.

I also learned that complex data types are nothing more than **classes**. The assignment using "new" then creates **objects** from these classes / complex data types, which in turn can be referred to as **objectives or complex variables**.

Now, with the **array**, I am not sure whether this is the same or should be understood differently. Because with the array (at least in java) an additional declaration is made, for example int [] = new int [6]; Since it looks so different to other complex data types and arrays are also referred to as data **structures**, I wanted to know whether I understood everything correctly and whether it can also be transferred to the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the Java programming language, arrays are objects (§4.3.1), are
> dynamically created, and may be assigned to variables of type Object
> (§4.3.2). All methods of class Object may be invoked on an array.

[From Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html)

Answer (score 1):

In java, arrays are objects, even if it's an array of primitive type.

For exemple :

```java
int[] array = {0,1,2,3};
// is the same as :
int[] array = new int[4];
array[0]=0;
array[1]=1;
array[2]=2;
array[3]=3;
// array[0] is primitive (int) but array is object
```

Answer (score 1):

In java, an array is just an object ([$4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1)), and you can check it yourself by a simple `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3};
    System.out.println(array.getClass().isPrimitive()); // returns false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java array are references as it was said adove,
int[] array = new int[]{1,2,3};
But be careful in Java some primitive types have an analog in reference types (int - Integer,  double - Double, etc). https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html.
Sometimes boxing/unboxing can produce waste memory and NullPointerException.
However, boxing/unboxing do not work for arrays (standard tools)